# Wordpress Customizer Hides my Sections / Controls inside of is_admin()

Tags: theme-customizer

Good evening,

I'm having a problem with the WordPress customizer. When the page loads it shows my controls, but after a fraction of a second an in-line style of `display: none` is added to them, resulting in them being hidden.

Can anyone give me some ideas as to what to look for? I've removed by `'active-callback'` argument to make it simpler.

All ideas welcomed - its driving me crazy!

EDIT:
Plenty more digging and it appears that it happens when the `add_action` is contained within an `if(is_admin()):`. Why would this be?

Cheers

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that `is_admin()` is conditional check specific to wp-admin and because the customizer doesn't actual have capability of displaying in wp-admin it would hide the controls.